# Not sure what is wrong with my mongo db statement

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to find the customers name with using the customer id.

this is my statement based on what I found in the mongo docs:

```
db.customer.find({"_id": "bf3Eva9zyWxJSaWK2"}, { "first_name": 1 });
```

but it is returning the id not name.

this is what I would do in sql:

```
SELECT first_name
FROM customer 
WHERE _id = "bf3Eva9zyWxJSaWK2"
```

This seems straight forward but I cant seem to get what I need, Any help is appreciated.

Comment: above query should work... Are you getting any error?

Comment: If you run the query with no filter `"db.customer.find({})"`, do you get any data? Also, could you perhaps post the document you are after or another sample document if you can locate one using e.g. Robo3T or something? Lastly, are you sure you are connected to the right database? Is there a type in the collection name?

Answer (score 0):

If the _id is auto generated, you need to write the following statement.

```
db.customer.find({"_id": ObjectId("bf3Eva9zyWxJSaWK2")}, { "first_name": 1 });
```

Answer (score 0):

to use `db.customer.find({"_id": "bf3Eva9zyWxJSaWK2"}, { "first_name": 1 });`

you must have to require `const { ObjectID } = require('mongodb')` or `const ObjectID  = require('mongodb').ObjectID`

then you use `db.customer.find({"_id": ObjctID("bf3Eva9zyWxJSaWK2")}, { "first_name": 1 });`

you will also use find Query like this

`db.customer.find({"_id": ObjctID("bf3Eva9zyWxJSaWK2")}, "first_name")`
`db.customer.find({"_id": ObjctID("bf3Eva9zyWxJSaWK2")}, ["first_name"])`